# Single sign out using Kentor assemblies

Tags: .net, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, kentor-authservices

Kentor provides the implementation to initiate single sign-out from SP.
However, in the latest Kentor assemblies the binding for sending the logout request is always HttpRedirect.

However, the identity provider rejects the logout request sent with the HttpRedirect binding and it wants the request to be sent with HttpPost.

I don't see any option to configure the binding for logout in the Kentor config section. Is there a way to change the logout binding without disturbing the Kentor code?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set a separate binding for logout requests in code, but that's unfortunately not implemented in `web.config` (which I assume you are using). You can change the `binding` attribute of the idp to make both the login in and logout messages use the same binding. But if you need them to use different bindings you either have to do that in code or add the config option to web.config. I added an [issue #465](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/issues/465) for that to keep it on the todo list.